# Cycript injection on iOS simulator got a CYPoolError

Tags: ios, iphone, cycript

As the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5d1cK0nq4GY#t=37m53s)
by Jay Freeman, we can inject the Cyript lib into iOS simulator, to debug our app dynamicly.

But when I do the operarion and tried `CYListenServer(5432);`
I got a crash: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type CYPoolError`

Anyone has some solutions?